# Extract a table from word document which is between certain text , docx.api, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatables, python-docx

I am trying to extract tables from a document consisting of 100 pages, the document is updated every week. The table headings remain consistent however the data inside the table changes every week. There are approx. 20-30 tables on different pages that needs to be extracted. All tables have a heading and in the end a text line after the table. how can I extract the table which is between heading and ending text , example, Table heading is

"This is a annual table x123"

```
<table>
```

and then ending text. " the above table is xxxx"

This is one example, i need to search based on the heading text for each table and then extract the tables from underneath it.

Currently the code i am using is extracting all tables from the doc table.

```
    from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document("C:/Users/user123/Desktop/Python/python_truncated_tables.docx")
tables = document.tables
df = pd.DataFrame()

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
        df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)

df.columns = ["Column1", "Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5", "Column6","Column7","Column8","Column9"]    
df.to_excel("C:/Users/user123/Desktop/Python/pythonoutput1.xlsx")

print(df)
```

Comment: Do you know the desired heading and ending strings in advance?

Comment: Yes, i have the heading and ending strings in advance. Heading and ending strings will remain constant for each individual table.

Comment: What have you tried in order to isolate those tables so far?

Comment: i tried converting the doc to pdf since pdf allow to extract content using page range , however the output i am getting in a dataframe from the pdf file is unreadable and missing out on data.

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't *just* getting text between two specified strings, but getting the text in the first place. Is that correct? If so, I'd re-frame your question to focus on that (but start by searching for other people who have solutions to getting the text from a PDF, which can be tough).

Comment: defining a page range , or pages would also work, any ideas ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244432/discussion-between-asgm-and-walkingbird).